# drop down according menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to make drop down according menu for `wordpress`. but getting trouble for `wordpress` render code and js. may be i can fix something on my js or can do something on my `wordpress` function it will work. the working and raw html version is **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyber007/wn358ban/)** if you click on projects then menu is open.

but wordpress menu render little bit different way, render version html is **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyber007/qz511o61/)**

see the difference raw html is like before

```
<li><div class="link">Projects<i class="icon-down"></i></div>
```

and render wordpress version is  `<li><a href="#">Projects</a>` so main difference is div and link class.

have any idea how can make it work ?

Answer (score 0):

Try providing id of the `<ul>`that holds the lists in href.

```
<li><a href="#Id of the ul">Projects</a>
```

or 
try using data-target

```
<li><a data-target="Id of the ul">Projects</a>
```

Comment: thanks for your comment. i think on my js this way not work for data-target or a id. or need different js for this. do you know any easy according  menu which can work for normal wordpress menu system. not plugins just raw js/css

Comment: @pagol sorry :/ No idea about that.